# What is @icloud.com domain name?

Tags: icloud, email

How do I email someone with a @icloud.com domain?

Do I use gmail normally, and send an email to the recipient?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Yes, you can use any email client like Gmail to email any email address including @icloud.com email addresses.

Comment: Question with recurrention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just like any other email address. You send email to it however you normally would.

Comment: It sounds like the person is asking, "how do I get one of those @icloud.com email addresses my friends have?"